Simple Horizontal layout of graph nodes in networks diagram
I have a dataframe containing flight connection data in a network representation



edge
source
target
type




ZRH_ZRH_-1_base_ZRH_PMI_470_flight_idle0_start
ZRH source
ZRH-PMI 470
start


ZRH_PMI_470_flight_PMI_ZRH_655_flight_idle70_sit
ZRH-PMI 470
PMI-ZRH 655
sit


PMI_ZRH_655_flight_ZRH_ZRH_-1_base_idle0_end
PMI-ZRH 655
ZRH sink
end


...
...
...
...



source or target are either a flight (e.g. ZRH-PMI 470) or a base (ZRH).
I'm trying to create the following diagram (the gray regions represent additional flight connections that are not present in the sample dataframe posted before, just to give an idea on how the final diagram should be)

I'm creating the network from the dataframe using
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    test,
    "source",
    "target",
    True,
     create_using=nx.DiGraph()
)

but the only way I can get kind of close to what I want is the
kamada_kawai_layout.

which looks weird because I don't think is supposed to be used like this.
Is there any way to create the layout without having to manually define the positions for every node? In the end I only want to organize the connections between child and parent on horizontal lines...nothing fancy. I tried to look into the multipartite_layout but I don't really have node attributes indicating the layers.

I realized the dot layout of graphviz (https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/dot/) was exactly what I needed.
I'm now creating the layout positions with
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot', args='-Grankdir="LR"')

which is giving me something similar to what I needed.
